# Improper position during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I have two swap-able divs using Jquery Drag and Drop.

When I am trying to swap  divs using drag the position of divs during animation is not proper. The swapping of divs is happening properly but problem is during animation.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="toz">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class='droppable'>
          <div class="draggable">Draggable 1</div>
        </div>

        <div class='droppable'>
          <div class="draggable">Draggable 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.startPos = window.endPos = {};

    makeDraggable();

  $('.droppable').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hoverClass',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $from = $(ui.draggable),
        $fromParent = $from.parent(),
        $to = $(this).children(),
        $toParent = $(this);

      window.endPos = $to.offset();

      swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 200);
      swap($to, window.endPos, window.startPos, 1000, function() {
        $toParent.html($from.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
        $fromParent.html($to.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: '',
          top: '',
          'z-index': ''
        }));
        makeDraggable();
      });
    }
  });

  function makeDraggable() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({
      zIndex: 99999,
      revert: 'invalid',
      start: function(event, ui) {
        window.startPos = $(this).offset();
      }
    });
  }

  function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
    $el.css('position', 'absolute')
      .css(fromPos)
      .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
        if (callback) callback();
      });
  }

});
```

[**Fiddle demo of problem**](https://jsfiddle.net/BKUM/2eysmghe/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply changing absolute to fixed worked. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2eysmghe/5/)

```
function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
    $el.css('position', 'fixed')
      .css(fromPos)
      .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
        if (callback) callback();
      });
  }
```

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: I changed position absolute to fixed

Comment: I mean why that happened ?